# How to show wordpress post url into post excerpt before READ MORE

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am interested to know how to add post permalink as TEXT to post excerpt before READ MORE button.
Ex. I have post with title "How to earn Money" with post permalink www.abc.com/how-to-earn-money.

Now issue is described below. 
Left side featured image that is ok. Post title will be shown as "how to earn money". Post excerpt will be shown as blah blah blah  with READ MORE button

Now I just want to add www.abc.com ( not full url) in the post excerpt before READ MORE button. Can u please tell how to do this?

I am not technical person to understand deeply, so I just want some piece of custom php code to add post permalink.

```
function replace_excerpt($content) {
       return str_replace('[...]',
               '<div class="more-link"><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">Continue Reading</a></div>',
               $content
       );
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_excerpt');
```

This is to replace excerpt text with url, but this is not working & I want to keep post excerpt as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to modify the excerpt, try to change your filter name to **get_the_excerpt**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_excerpt

```php
function modify_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    global $post;

    $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_url', true );
    $excerpt .= str_replace( $excerpt, '[...]', '<br/>' . $url );

    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'modify_excerpt' );
```

Comment: Sjors,  I forgot to mention that posts are coming from different websites. I use them for my research. www.abc.com is not solution. I want single code to paste in functions.php file if it is possible.To explain it deeply that data is coming from selected rss feeds which I am using. so If I get single code to paste, it will be very helpful . thanks in advance.

Comment: I can help you to solve your problem, but I'm not here to do all the coding for you.. :) What you can do is make the $post variable global and then you can get the meta value of that post which stores the URL you want to show. Modified the code example above.

Comment: yes. I can understand. Actually I searched a lot, but I didn't get it anywhere. tx for tips. If anyone from stackoverflow write code for me, it would help because I can't appoint developer for this small work.

Comment: I think you have edited code if I am not wrong. But, it is not working. tx

Comment: I'm sorry but you really need to do some programming yourself. This isn't a platform for non-programmers to get coding work done for free. I can help you, but you need to do some work yourself.